Vercel environment variables - ROOT_PATH
I built my first Next.js project which I've deployed to Vercel which all works nicely except for the image upload control, when I try to upload I'm getting errors because the root path is wrong
Part of my .env file
POSTGRES_DATABASE="verceldb"
ROOT_PATH=/Users/Admin/Documents/websites/next/my-project/ # path to project 

This makes sense because it's the path on my local pc
I obviously need to change this. I had a search, couldn't really find anything? what do I change ROOT_PATH to?
